# How to find all records where date is later than?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase db like the one below:

[image]

and I'd like to select all events that come after a certain date.  I've attempted to do this with the following code:

```
events := []data.EventData{}

if err := ref.Child("date").OrderByValue().StartAt(time.Now()).Get(c, events); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error selecing upcoming events")
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    response.Message = "Problem getting upcoming events"
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response)
    return
}
```

But it keeps throwing the error:

> Index not defined, add ".indexOn": ".value", for path "/Event/date",
>   to the rules

What does this mean and how do I go about selecting the records that I need?  Am I on the right track and just need to resolve this error or should I be taking a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is asking you add an index to `date` to improve query performance. AFAIK, you are able to get data you need without adding any index. But it will be quite slow as your `event` data grow. check the link for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: But it's returning an error when I try to get my records so that means it's more than a suggestion right?

Comment: is there any data in your `events` slice? @AbeMiessler

Comment: No it's empty.  Could there be a problem with my query that is causing it to return no results?  It sounds like you are pretty sure it should have results even though it's throwing an error?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, seems firebase is not just suggesting, the index is required. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing. code is here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/db/query.go#L113.